# GUI code generation based on class

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, code-generation

I am looking for a sw tool to generate somehow c# source code for a user interface input form based on existing classes.

To be more specific, I have a class that represents a person, eg. a person object based on class as simple as that having, string properties like id, name, surname also number properties like age, height, weight, also date properties like birthday and methods like read, write, delete etc. Make it as generic as you like.

Now i am looking to generate source code for a windows form (web form will follow a similar way) mapping eg. the string properties to text boxes, numbers the same, methods to buttons and actions etc. It would be nice if one can use configuration and options to tune the code generation.

If you have ever used DevExpress, what I am looking for is something like or similar to the GUI generator that this commercial tool have.

Thanks in advance for your time and support.
semag

Comment: It has been a while since I've done WinForms, but I'm pretty sure if you can get the type to show up in the Toolbox, you can just drag it to the designer and it will do this.  How to get it in the Toolbox, I don't remember.

Comment: Question closed? Why? thought it was ok myself. @Semag is trying to generate his UI from the underlying entity model.... seems pretty normal.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that binding to a simple property sheet would be a good place to start.